# Using a variable as array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

I have a data structure like so:

```
var questions {
  'foo' : [
    {
      'question' : 'Where do babies come from?',
      'choice' : [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
    },
    {
      'question' : 'What is the meaning of life?',
      'choice' : [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
    }
  ],
  'bar' : [
    {
      'question' : 'Where do babies come from?',
      'choice' : [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
    },
    {
      'question' : 'What is the meaning of life?',
      'choice' : [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to navigate and select various data contextually. I need `bar` and `1` in `questions.bar[1].question` to be variable. I have written the following and have had no success:

```
var quiz = $('[id*="Quiz"]');
var skill = quiz.attr('id').substring(0, 3); // 'foo' or 'bar'
var string = '';

for(var i = 0; i < questions[skill].length; i++) {

  var baz = skill + '[' + i + ']'; // need to produce 'foo[0]' or 'bar[0]'

  string += (
    '<div>' +
    '<p>' + questions[baz].question + '</p>' // need to select questions.foo[0].question or questions.bar[0] and then print '<p>Where do babies come from?</p>'
  );
}
```

If anyone knows how to make the array name itself a variable, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: `questions[skill].length` need to be `questions.skill.length` (if you are sure that `skill` is coming as `foo` or `bar`)

Comment: @AlivetoDie that doesn't look right at all. There is no `skill` property

Comment: @phil  in his code he created that variable and writen there that it's coming like foo or bar

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes, but `questions.skill` is undefined. The correct code is `questions[skill].length`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should do the trick; you just need to pull the array value as you normally would:

```
var baz = questions[skill][i]; // will be `foo[i]` or `bar[i]`
```

This works because `questions[skill]` is a reference to the array, whose elements can then be accessed as usual. So then you would simply do the following to pull the question text:

```
'<p>' + baz.question + '</p>'
```